# Missing References when I copy my computer to a new location

Tags: vb.net, reference

I have inherited a VB project and have tried to copy it to my laptop from the original desktop machine.  It is missing the Adobe Acrobat 10 Type Library and Interop.GrooveAPIPrivate COMS.  I noticed an answer pointing to downloading the Acrobat SDK and adding a reference but this gives me an error saying "make sure it is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

Interms of the GrooveAPIPrivate i have no idea why I would need this as the project is a company database project.

Has anyone any ideas why I cant install these COMs?

Comment: Exactly what steps did you take with the Acrobat SDK?

Comment: I have just installed DC pro and that seems to have solved it.  I have no idea why!

Comment: I still have the issue with GrooveAPIPrivate.  If i go to the working project the reference is a COM and the path points to Interop.GrooveAPIPrivate.dll.  when I brovse to this reference location on my laptop I see the file Interop.GrooveAPIPrivate.dll but when I bring it in through add reference it comes into the project as a .NET assembly.  I really have no idea what I am doing when it comes to this.

Comment: That sounds like a company-internal COM library - we really can't help you with that because COM registration is like a thousand monkeys all with their own ideas (whatever that means - I'm actually really high right now lol), but anyway, you **really need** to track down the last maintainer of the project and get their instructions for getting your machine working, and then **WRITE DOWN AN ONBOARDING FILE!** for future reference for yourself and more importantly: _for others in the future_.

Comment: Thanks Dai - Onboarding is top of the agenda over the next while!!

Comment: In addition to what Dai has said,  might also pay to review the code.  You could find that GrooveAPIPrivet was a reference added to the project but never actually used and can safely be removed, or easily superseded

Comment: I tried doing that by simply deleting it but it seemed to give me a load of warnings.  I could not find anything in the code that used the word Groove.  Is there a better way than the standard find function to look for references?